# How to get a HTML element to span same class but not be linked

Tags: html, razor

I have the following .cshtml code:

```
<p class="bolded">
                    @ResourceManager.GetResource("VerifyCode")
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="resend-button link do-trigger-overlay">
                        @ResourceManager.GetResource("VerifyRequestNewCode")
                        <span class="error-tooltip arrow-up">
                            @ResourceManager.GetResource("VerifyLostEmail")
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </p>
```

I am not very experienced with HTML. Currently the tooltip displays in the correct place, it is part of the link. If I remove the tooltip out of the  tags, the link is removed, but it the design of it doesn't point neatly at the link. My question is how can I get the tooltip error to be in this place but not be a link?

Comment: just remove this lines `<a href="javascript:;" class="resend-button link do-trigger-overlay">` and  `</a>`

Comment: Thanks @BurhamB.Soliman but the `@ResourceManager.GetResource("VerifyRequestNewCode")` needs to remain a link